# How to get rid of < > { } highlight in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I switched from Notepad++ to VSCode. Every thing is nice except for this highlighter. I found no use for it right now and would like to remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
"editor.matchBrackets": false
```

[More info about VSCode settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)